# Copy an pasted code from paper.js site to codepen no longer working

Tags: paperjs, codepen

Hello I'm trying to get SymbolDefinitions working in a pen. The exapmle on paper.js site works perfectly but when I port the code to codepen, it no longer works. There are a couple of tweaks for the codepen to install paper in the window `paper.install(window) and paper.setup('canvas')`

Here is the code

```
paper.install(window);
paper.setup("canvas");
var path = new Path.Star(new Point(100, 100), 10, 5, 13);
path.style = {
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'black'
};

// Create a symbol definition from the path:
var definition = new SymbolDefinition(path);

// Place 100 instances of the symbol definition:
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Place an instance of the symbol definition in the project:
    var instance = definition.place();

    // Move the instance to a random position within the view:
    instance.position = Point.random() * view.size;

    // Rotate the instance by a random amount between
    // 0 and 360 degrees:
    instance.rotate(Math.random() * 360);

    // Scale the instance between 0.25 and 1:
    instance.scale(0.25 + Math.random() * 0.75);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use PaperScript directly by placing your code in a `<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas"></script/` tag in the HTML part of your codepen.
Here is a [demonstration](https://codepen.io/sasensi/pen/bGBqXOy).